# Calling methods in Typescript strict mode

Tags: typescript

I have this code, that I have converted from plain js in Typescript:

```
type Paragraph = { paragraph: (data: { text: string }) => string };
type Header = { header: (data: { level: string; text: string }) => string };
type List = { list: (data: { style: string; items: string[] }) => string };

type Block = {
    type: string;
    data: string;
};

export default class HTMLEngine {
    static get generators(): Paragraph & Header & List {
        return {
            paragraph: (data: { text: string }) => `<p>${data.text}</p>`,

            header: (data: { level: string; text: string }) => `<h${data.level}>${data.text}</h${data.level}>`,

            list: (data: { style: string; items: string[] }) => {
                const tagname = `${data.style.charAt(0)}l`;
                return `<${tagname}>${data.items.map(item => `<li>${item}</li>`)}</${tagname}>`;
            }
        };
    }

    render(ejsData: string): string {
        try {
            const parsed = JSON.parse(ejsData).blocks;
            return parsed.reduce((output: string, block: Block) => output + this.renderBlock(block), '');
        } catch (e) {
            return ejsData || '';
        }
    }

    renderBlock(block: Block): string {
        return `${HTMLEngine.generators[block.type](block.data)}\n`;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly but in strict mode I get this error on this line

```
return `${HTMLEngine.generators[block.type](block.data)}\n`;
```

```
(property) HTMLEngine.generators: Paragraph & Header & List
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Paragraph & Header & List'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Paragraph & Header & List'.ts(7053)
```

I have no clue on fixing this error.
Could someone help?

Comment: You try to access generators as an object, but it is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that your `Block` type isn't precise enough. So the `type` of a `Block` shouldn't be just a `string` but `'paragraph' | 'header' | 'list'` to match the types `Paragraph`, `Header` and `List`.

Same for the `data` attribute, it should be `{ text: string } & { level: string; text: string } & { style: string; items: string[] }`.

So your `Block` type will look like that:

```js
type Block = {
    type: 'paragraph' | 'header' | 'list';
    data: { text: string } & { level: string; text: string } & { style: string; items: string[] };
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgcyWAFlAvFA3lMRFNdALigAoATOYOc-YCAD2HIGdgEBLAO2SgBfAJTYAfFE49+QgNwBYAFChIUABIQ4VCAmx4o6TdoTlqtevoA2EAG4RLHLn2SyoTVo+kCR4yU5mCCsrg0AAy3Jx6+JYRbJQ0dAx+INaezq7cTAC27Gn8ANoAukKiWBJSznJKSirQAEKWAPYAxgDWUUpQXW4h5ADkhEiocBh9UAA+AAV9hlo6Y+NQfTGcfUHdUAkWjCxxFQFQAGST0bb2eS5uuxdCRyfJqX5eGdm5T85FVYqB1YosYI0EMBNhAAGZwACulmBzUscHY7HUABUALKhACi-D40FwnW6nFo3GaUGQEGBpN4OlogPYFGE5HgQxIR3URh0LPCkVxig2GwQZIhCF4eDxvN5g2IIzI8XMSXce383lKEgABgAeMBiAAkuC2ADp5YI1QB6TUqgA0vzFYtmxlMWyS1jsDne-Fc8puPjKUHV6B1+qd9kE2t15gNuyNxr9oboesDlmDFqt1o2KziZkS+k4KQgFxeEByF0+Xok3JTKeajV4kToyF4cCy0BwKv9Yez1j1zXQiAAgsAKAAGYSCSwq9blsX84CC4XqnW1+uN4Ot2OZAvsPVZEYUNdZXzqmIh3eRw8q4cm+coRcQRPjieCUW8n487oPxSP-m8YwUCAAK3YAAisqusg9IgSKL5ilwIAQROXSVtWwKDOwEBUHoABSADKADyAByerIRAP7-kBdDCHqABGTRtOwd7llOM4EIgKFUHq-JUBCzRERQjQQsAYB8Rc5pQFRLStOQDRicqUC8fxfFQAA1G46ARGxEBfjokltBQoltMIwl9H0wh0RsghQM0tBdpQECiGWcEMUKUB-oB5gTIshkma+j5vh+6nGFprQ6dR4lQAFYH7AIdmTgKjktrgaiohiWKUnqFJUsANL5LprQGiEhRBWJepbMOAA6vBjt5SiCEAA)

Comment: I doubt any `Block` will have its `data` property contain all three of those types.  It rightfully should be a union and not an intersection, but then you want `Block` to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions).

Comment: @johannchopin thank you, your code and explanation helped me and let me understand my error!

Comment: @Valerio you should make sure that your `Block` values really conform to the type suggested here.  Try making the change and calling `renderBlock()` on, say, `{type: "paragraph", data: {text: "xyz"}`.  The compiler will report an error and tell you that, for example, `{text: "xyz"}` is missing properties like `level` and `style`.  Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `Block` to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) type where its `type` property determines exactly what type the `data` property will be.  You can write that manually, or, if you want, generate this programmatically from your `Paragraph`, `Header`, and `List`:

```
type AllBlocks = Paragraph & Header & List;
type Block = { [K in keyof AllBlocks]: { type: K, data: Parameters<AllBlocks[K]>[0] } }[keyof AllBlocks]
/* type Block = {
    type: "paragraph";
    data: {
        text: string;
    };
} | {
    type: "header";
    data: {
        level: string;
        text: string;
    };
} | {
    type: "list";
    data: {
        style: string;
        items: string[];
    };
} */
```

---

This doesn't exactly solve your problem though, due to TypeScript's lack of support for what I've been calling *correlated record types* (see [Microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more information).  The compiler sees  `HTMLEngine.generators[block.type]` and `block.data` as unrelated union types that might not be usable together, even though `block.data` is always appropriate for the function you get with `block.type`.

Currently you can work around this by writing redundant code to walk the compiler through the possibilities:

```
renderBlock(block: Block): string {
    switch (block.type) {
        case "header":
            return `${HTMLEngine.generators[block.type](block.data)}\n`;
        case "list":
            return `${HTMLEngine.generators[block.type](block.data)}\n`;
        case "paragraph":
            return `${HTMLEngine.generators[block.type](block.data)}\n`;
    }
}
```

or, (more reasonably), use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler not to worry about its inability to verify safety here:

```
renderBlock(block: Block): string {
    const generator = HTMLEngine.generators[block.type] as (x: Parameters<AllBlocks[keyof AllBlocks]>[0]) => string;
    return `${generator(block.data)}\n`;
}
```

or the simpler

```
renderBlock(block: Block): string {
    return `${HTMLEngine.generators[block.type](block.data as any)}\n`;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.3#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgcyWAFlAvFA3lMRFNdALigAoATOYOc-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-fLI-15uW7irEe79vgxqpEO9IbNkuRQcgRQlL49ZAR27StLwkR0MgvBPNAOBjreL4QRA87tOgiB1MAFAAsIgiWGO5qoZiTbAC2bYTrO2G4c8j5Ed+lo5POWSDBQgm+BOMRPoJ75SWOdErlxKA8RA-5MR2giCqSyraYBLE5sYFAQAAVuwAAi-Z0sgxbwe2coICAdlAehmGegS7AQFQegAFIAMoAPIAHLzu5EBGaZFl0MI84AEbQuw6liqx7EEIgHlUPOTZUL67RhRQrS+sAYCFQqtxxYs5DfJ0l5QAVRWFVAADUbjoBEmUGToVUUOVXTCLcADk-XCIlQhQO0tDkZQECiChzHJa2UAmeZ5hQCybKDSNmkNltgpNrwxhVQASp5vr7XAvDUT1nSVdCNlWU5pLsAA7pkk3ddCi4hDNWloSG0A8uMCC4qQP2ofNHGzhG0ZxsgCbzpmuZIMABb5Fdn2QIU72LPO9x0QAOrwjGg1S40edyWrAMDxNbuD46Q1Gsbxrm8M5nmyNvKjH21JjaO44IBNEw2W6k-9XZlugVNC3NzYLYRuBQ4zsPMwjbMo2j3NY10OPmPjhObUqelQHtB3QnUoY6Jd0I3Ysd3ng9WIuZEKtI+6egKzDcPO-mHPqyExQhpQzAlkQzyvB8UKLOwYI7PshyNFVZz-ECNVWSNtNy177Oa502tRfzesG4ou0dQgVVmx5HoAEzZ9bvUKvb+lsbL9PQ0zpGZ2rXN+9nudwFAAfnSAuuC7pRdj4IQA)

Comment: This is actually a better and more strict implementation. I'll check it out